# Specify colors, axis lines, and removal of background in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, formatting, geom-bar

Where and how do I specify colors, axis lines, and removal of background in geombar? Ultimately, I want to have one bar to be dark gray and one bar to be light gray. They are currently blue and pink which were defaults. I also want the the x and y to have axis lines, and the figure to have no gray background. I have everything else figured out, using the below code. Thank you for your help.

```
library(ggplot2)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
limits <- aes(ymax = myData$mean + myData$se,
              ymin = myData$mean - myData$se)

p <- ggplot(data = myData, aes(x = names, y = mean, fill = names)) +

p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = dodge) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.9) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())
limits <- aes(ymax = myData$mean + myData$se,
              ymin = myData$mean - myData$se)

p <- ggplot(data = myData, aes(x = factor(site), y = mean,
                               fill = factor(infectionstatus)))

p + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
         position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = position_dodge(0.9),
            width = 0.25) +
  labs(x = "Sites", y = "Average Calories in White Muscle Tissue")  +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Infection Status")
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted something like this:

```
# Generate data
myData <- data.frame(names = letters[1:2],
                     mean  = 1:2,
                     SE    = 0.1)

# Plot data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(myData, aes(names, mean)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = names),
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - SE, ymax = mean + SE),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), width = 0.5) +
    labs(title = "Calorie Amount",
         subtitle = "Averaged per Tissue",
         x = NULL, 
         y = "Average Calories in White Muscle Tissue",
         fill = "Infection Status") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey40", "grey60")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

I used `theme_classic()` as it does most of the job when you want clean plot. And specified colors with `scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey40", "grey60"))`

Comment: @Mary can you please accept my answer if it solved your problem